# RDD operation in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two RDD's

```
x = [("XYZ",12),("ABC",15),("PQR",20)]
y = [("XY",100),("AB",200),("PQR",123),("MNO",111)]
```

I need final result such as "XY" is sub string of "XYZ", so I want to merge this two tuple into one. Result for above example is as follow,

```
result = [("XYZ",12,100),("ABC",15,200),("PQR",20,123)]
```

Right now I have achieved this using for loop. 
is there any better way to solve this ?

Comment: Pls show your code that is using for loop.  The problem is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think cartesian join resolves your issue:

```
>>> x.cartesian(y).filter(lambda r: r[1][0] in r[0][0]) \
...     .map(lambda r: (r[0][0], r[0][1], r[1][1])).collect()
[('XYZ', 12, 100), ('ABC', 15, 200), ('PQR', 20, 123)]
```